# Adjust leaflet map's brightness using filter css property

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am trying to adjust brightness (not the opacity) of the leaflet map by using default css property "filter: brightness(1.0);" and kind of adding slider functionality as well like below link.

[Leaflet Example](http://jsbin.com/zisenujole/edit?html,css,js,output) - Changing opacity to filter: brightness(1.0);

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  opacity: 0
}).addTo(mymap);

var slider = document.getElementById('opacity-slider');
slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var value = Number(e.target.value);
  var opacity = value / 100;
  tileLayer.setOpacity(opacity);
});
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to adjust the brightness of the *map* or the brightness of the *tile layer*?

Comment: brightness of the map probably using filter but if it was possible to adjust the brightness of the tile layer, that would be cool.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266211/changing-brightness-of-wms-layer-in-leaflet). Is it helpful?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, use filter: brightness() but achieve it using slider and having difficulty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" class="slider" id="brightness-slider">
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
tileLayer.getContainer().style.filter = 'brightness(0%)';

var slider = document.getElementById('brightness-slider');
slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  tileLayer.getContainer().style.filter = 'brightness(' + value + '%)';
});
```

Try it out in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/setehil/4/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. 

Comment: So I have clusters like this on the map. http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/clustering-feature-layers.html

I want to reduce the brightness of the map and not the clusters. any idea?

Comment: Could you ask this as a separate question? More of the community will be able to pitch in that way.